# If action_name Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using if action_name to define a layout, for example

```
layout :layout_by_action_name

def layout_by_action_name
  if action_name == 'new'
    "layout_file"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

How can I add another action name with `new`, such as `edit`. I tried:

```
layout :layout_by_action_name

def layout_by_action_name
  if action_name == 'new' && 'edit'
    "layout_file"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
if action_name == "new" or action_name == "edit"
```

Or:

```
if ["new", "edit"].include? action_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
if action_name == 'new' || action_name == 'edit'
```

Comment: Is `||` the equivalent of `or`?

Comment: well, it's not
`or` and `and` are control flow operators when `||` and `&&` are boolean.

Comment: See this link for more information: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

So I tried MrDanA's answer but it needed brackets to work, like this:

```
if ["new", "edit"].include?(action_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.1+ provides the `in?` method, so you could now write this:

```rb
layout :layout_by_action_name

def layout_by_action_name
  if action_name.in?('new','edit')
    'layout_file'
  else
    'application'
  end
end
```

And in Rails 4+ you can do it even more succinctly because layout takes a proc:

```rb
layout ->{ action_name.in?('new','edit') ? 'layout_file' : 'application' }
```

At the other end of the scale, if you have a particularly complex set of requirements then a case statement may make more sense:

```rb
def layout_by_action_name
  case action_name
  when 'new','edit'
    'layout_file'
  when 'delete'
    'other_file'
  else
    'application'
  end
end
```

And finally, you can do it the old fashioned way by specifying the layout in your `render` call:

```rb
def new
  ...
  render layout: 'layout_file'
end

def edit
  ...
  render layout: 'layout_file'
end
```

This last one may even be the best option if you're only overriding the layout for a small number of actions, because it's very clear.